# I need a way to structure my laravel Controller with lot of scripts?

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.2 to build a website contains small scripts. The problem is I don't know how to organize this scripts to add more in future.

My first thought was to create a Helpers folder in App and create class for every script with a function that return the result I want.

The problem now in the controller I don't want to create a function for every script or class from those.

I have one controller with a function named "result" receive an $id (the id of the script).

When the user select a script and wait for a result, how to make the result function to call the proper script by its id from database?

Do I need to use a `switch` or `if` and add more conditions in future every time I create new script?

I hope you understand the idea
and take the scripts as a small games just a class with static function return a result.

Update:
code example

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

...
use App\Helpers\Helpers;

class PlayController extends Controller
{
    public function result(Request $request,$id)
    {
        //get user data ($data) 

        //here the first problem
        $result = Helpers::createImage_script1($data);

        return view('result')->with("picture",$result);
    }
}
```

first problem how to select the function Depending on the $id

i created a class helpers in new folder App/Helpers and i don't know if i will create all my functions in one class or create a class for every function in future because i will create more in future

and i don't want every time i create new class to use the term " use App\Helpers\Newclass;" in the controller what if i create 30 class !

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class Helpers
{
    public static function createImage_script1($data)
    {
        //use the data and create an image

        return $image;
    }
}
```

i don't know how to explain more :)
this example is for 1 script how to make it work for 10 script (functions in other folder)

Comment: Probably this question is way too broad: could you add some code example ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem having a lot of files, the problem comes when you try to assign many responsibilities to a controller.  I encourage you to check out the repository pattern which would be helpful in your case. If you have a Laracast account take a look: https://laracasts.com/lessons/decorating-repositories